# Distance of point from a line not working

Tags: java, android

I am calculating distance of point from a line. But I am getting wrong distance. Following is my piece of code which is gettting distance from line.

```
float px,py,something,u;
px=x2-x1;
py=y2-y1;

something = px*px + py*py;

u =  ((x - x1) * px + (y - y1) * py) /(something);


if( u > 1)
{
    u = 1;
    // MinDist=0;
}
else if (u < 0)
{
    u = 0;
    //MinDist=0;
}


float xx = x1 + u * px;
float yy = y1 + u * py;

float dx = xx - x;
float dy = yy - y;

float dist= (float)Math.sqrt((double)dx*dx +(double) dy*dy);
```

Dist is giving wrong answer.

Comment: Suggest you review this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation

Comment: is there any algo available for that?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exactly is given? Is line's equation given? In what form? Might have helped if you were using proper variable names, providing comments, and not using variable names like `something`.

Comment: no i have points placed in buffer i took points from buffer and then compare it with line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line#Vector_formulation

```
distance(x=a+tn, p) = ||(a-p)-((a-p).n)n||
```

Where:

```
a = (x1, y1)              //First point on line
n = |(x2-x1, y2-y1)|      //Normalised direction vector
p = (x, y)                //Query point
```

So, not going to do it all, but make functions and give meaningful names to help you follow the formular:

```
float[] a = new float[]{x1, y1};
float[] n = new float[]{x2-x1, y2-y1};
normalize(n);
float[] p = new float[]{x, y};

float[] aMinusP = subtract(a, p);
float aMinusPDotn = dot(aMinusP, n);

// vec2a.vec2b
float dot(float[] vec2a, float[] vec2b)
{
   return vec2a[0]*vec2b[0] + vec2a[1]*vec2b[1];
}

// ||vec2||
float len(float[] vec2)
{
   return (float)Math.Sqrt(dot(vec2, vec2));
}

// vec2/||vec2||
void normalize(float[] vec2)
{
  float length = len(vec2);
  vec2[0] /= length;
  vec2[1] /= length;
}

// vec2a - vec2b
float[] subtract(float[] vec2a, float[] vec2b)
{
  return new float[]{vec2a[0]-vec2b[0],vec2a[1]-vec2b[1]};
}
```

Comment: sqrt of soemthing is giving distance?

Comment: sir point is (x,y) and line is (x1,y1)(x2,y2). i want to calculate distance of point from line

Comment: sir your above code is giving distance between 2 points i want to have distance between a point and a line.

Comment: thanks for replying me back i wanna ask i more stupid question what is ||(a-p)-((a-p).n)n|| this. I mean after calculating (a-p)-((a-p).n)n what this ||x|| stands for?

Comment: `x` is a vector, and `||x||` is the application of pythagorus theroum to find the length. See my `len` function, that is `||vec2||`.

Comment: now sir i have to do distance=|(aminusp)-(aminuspdotn)*n| and if i am right then i have also calculate aminusp? as you didnt have mention above?

Comment: 1 last thing a*n means (a.x*n*x,a.y*n*y)?

Comment: Opps I meant to do a minus p, have corrected. And there is no `a*n` so I don't know what you mean there. There is `aMinusPDotn*n` which is `(aMinusPDotn * n.x, aMinusPDotn * n.y)` as `aMinusPDotn` is just a scalar (a single float)

Comment: sir thank you very much. You have helped me a lot. I want just 1 more thing as i am unable to found so i want an example just to check weather i am getting correct result or not

Comment: i didnt find an example with a point and 2 other points making a line. what i found is a point and an equation of line.

Comment: Just draw one out on grid paper and measure the distance with a ruler. But how did you know your original was wrong without knowing the correct results?

Comment: What good is just one example anyway, I can give you an example all too easily: Line (0,0)=>(0,1) Point (0,1) Distance to line = 1. If it works for that, does that prove it works for all?

Comment: `Line (0,0)=>(0,1) Point (0,1) Distance to line = 1. If it works for that, does that prove it works for all?` No. It probably doesn't work at all then. Distance of point (0,1) to Line (0,0)=>(0,1) would be `zero`. I guess you meant to use `Point (1,0)`.